# Search for and replace a value in a vector of structs

Tags: c++, vector, struct, lambda

I am trying to compare a string to a struct element in a vector of structs and, if the values match, replace value in the struct element with a new value. I am able to populate the vector fine but I'm having issues getting the search and replace to work.

```
struct info {
    string name;
    string phone;
    string address;
}
vector<info> data;
```

At first I simply tried to loop through each element in the vector and compared the current value with the string. If they matched, I replaced the current value with the new value. This seemed to work, although the new value would revert back to the old one. I assume I'm changing a copy but I don't understand why. Here's the code.

```
for (auto e : data)
{
    if (e.name == old_name)  { e.name = new_name; }
}
```

My most recent attempt uses [std::replace_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/replace_if/) and a lambda expression to do the search and replace.

```
std::replace_if(data.begin(), data.end(), [old_name](info i){ return i.name == old_name; }, new_name);
```

However, the code doesn't compile and gives the following error - C2679 binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Can anyone help me understand what's going on?

Comment: There has got to be more to the error message than that. Switch from the Error List tab to the Output tab and see if the full build output provides better information.

Comment: Probably unrelated: `using namespace std;` [strikes a blow for the forces of evil!](https://godbolt.org/z/afCQSN)

Comment: [Here is the complete error message provided by Visual Studio](https://godbolt.org/z/kSQY3R) (via godbolt's Compiler Explorer). Provides much more useful information. You can see that it's trying to assign `std::string` to `info`. Kinda moot now thanks to cigien, but the full error message from the Ooutput tab can point you in the right direction much faster than the snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the elements in the vector, you need to take a reference in the range-for loop:

```
for (auto &e : data)
```

Otherwise you are making a copy, which doesn't change the original elements.

The 4th parameter of `replace_if` needs to take an `info` object, not just the `new_name` value.

Instead of `replace_if`, the appropriate algorithm to use here would be `for_each`, which modifies the `info` objects as needed:

```
std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), 
               [old_name, new_name](info &i) { 
                 if (i.name == old_name)
                    i.name = new_name;
              });
```

However, in this case, the range-for loop is probably less code, and easier to read and write.

Also, please avoid `using namespace std;`, it's bad practice.

Comment: That's it! I know I was missing something obvious. Thank you for the help.

Comment: No worries, glad to help. As a comment to your question points out, get into the habit of reading the compiler error messages, and you'll be able to solve a lot of problems on your own :)

Comment: If you want to go with an algorithm approach, [`std::for_each()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) would make more sense then `std::transform()`, eg: `std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [old_name, new_name](info &i) { if (i.name == old_name) i.name = new_name; });` But yeah, that is really not better than using a range-for loop instead.